# Repeating the watermark in the background

Tags: watermark

How to insert watermark repeatedly in the background only in the titlepage in an inclined fashion. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\backgroundsetup{%
  scale=1,       
  angle=0,         
  opacity=.6,    
  color =black,  
  contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node at ([yshift=11pt,xshift=5pt]current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}};    
    \end{tikzpicture}}
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

The code where I wish to implement this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{background}

\newlength{\drop}

\backgroundsetup{%
  scale=1,       %% change accordingly
  angle=0,       %% change accordingly
  opacity=.6,    %% change accordingly
  contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node at ([yshift=11pt,xshift=5pt]current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{logo}};    %% yshift and xshift for example only
    \end{tikzpicture}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\drop=0.1\textheight
\centering
\vspace*{\baselineskip}
\rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt}
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\\[\baselineskip]
{\LARGE\bfseries JAVA\\[0.3\baselineskip] {\Large Core Concepts}}\\[0.2\baselineskip]
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\\[\baselineskip]
    {\Large\bfseries BY \\[2mm]SUBHAM SONI}\\[\baselineskip]
    \includegraphics{logo}\\[1.2cm]
    {\Large\scshape May 27, 2014}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

The logo:
[image]

The way bookmark to be filled:

[image]

Comment: In which title page? Your example code doesn't show how are you producing this page. Are you using the `titlepage` environment? What do you mean by "repeatedly"? How many times? All the times with the same angle?

Comment: Yes @GonzaloMedina

Comment: @GonzaloMedina please see the edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load the `background` package with the `pages=some` option and then use `\BgThispage` for the title page; using a `minipage` for the contents and enough copies of the image, you get the desired result:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\DupImage{%
     \includegraphics[width=5cm]{logo}\hfill%  
     \includegraphics[width=5cm]{logo}\hfill%  
     \includegraphics[width=5cm]{logo}\hfill%  
     \includegraphics[width=5cm]{logo}\hfill%  
     \includegraphics[width=5cm]{logo}\hfill%  
     \includegraphics[width=5cm]{logo}\hfill%  
     \includegraphics[width=5cm]{logo}\hfill% 
}

\newlength{\drop}

\backgroundsetup{%
  scale=1,       %% change accordingly
  angle=45,       %% change accordingly
  opacity=.3,    %% change accordingly
  contents={%
     \begin{minipage}{1.5\paperheight}
     \DupImage\\[2ex]
     \DupImage\\[2ex]
     \DupImage\\[2ex]
     \DupImage\\[2ex]
     \DupImage\\[2ex]
     \DupImage\\[2ex]
     \DupImage\\[2ex]
     \DupImage\\[2ex]
     \DupImage\\[2ex]
     \DupImage
     \end{minipage}% 
   }  
}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\drop=0.1\textheight
\BgThispage
\centering
\vspace*{\baselineskip}
\rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt}
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\\[\baselineskip]
{\LARGE\bfseries JAVA\\[0.3\baselineskip] {\Large Core Concepts}}\\[0.2\baselineskip]
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\\[\baselineskip]
    {\Large\bfseries BY \\[2mm]SUBHAM SONI}\\[\baselineskip]
    \includegraphics{logo}\\[1.2cm]
    {\Large\scshape May 27, 2014}
\end{titlepage}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No This is not What I wanted...

Comment: @subhamsoni Then what is it?

Comment: Please see the edited question

Comment: @subhamsoni PLease see my new update. Is it something like this what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yup. But instead of the example image, the logo must come and a gap between them (if possible)

Comment: @subhamsoni Please see my updated answer. Change the number of images in `\DupImage` and/or the spacing and the value used in `\\[2ex]` according tto your needs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14754/discussion-between-subham-soni-and-gonzalo-medina).