# how do I draw text above images using the background package?

Tags: backgrounds, watermark

I am working on repeating a watermark as [answered here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180639/repeating-the-watermark-in-the-background?answertab=votes#tab-top)  Using that approach I find the drawn background always appears below images added using `\includegraphics`. 
Take the following document:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\backgroundsetup{
  color=red,
  angle=45,
  opacity=.8,
  contents={\large{Hellow World}}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{wikimedia}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Rendering a PDF with [tectonic](https://tectonic-typesetting.github.io/) works but the image added always appears on top:[image: rendered PDF with graphic clobbering watermark text]

Is there a way to configure [background package](https://ctan.org/pkg/background) or another setting so that the `Hello World` text below always appears on top of everything in the document? I do realize that the name of the package suggests otherwise.

Or should I invest more time solving this with [KOMA Script's](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) `scrlayer-scrpage` or another alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Well the background package uses the everypage package, at this package is only about adding background material.

I personally prefer to use the eso-pic package (also because background uses a tikzpicture which makes it difficult to use them in the material). But if you want to stay with background you could try to tweak background:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\makeatletter
\let \AddEverypageHook \AddToShipoutPictureFG
\renewcommand\AddThispageHook{\AddToShipoutPictureFG*}
\ifbg@some
  \AddThispageHook{}
\else
  \AddEverypageHook{\bg@material}
\fi
\makeatother

\backgroundsetup{
  color=red,
  angle=45,
  opacity=.8,
  contents={\large{Hellow World}},
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-duck}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting!  Something eso-pic can do that everypage cannot.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and working example. How would you achieve the layered text using eso-pic directly without using background?